# What is the equivalent of "form-group has-error" in Boostrap 4?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make form. When we send information with errors, then should be color red where we entered wrong data and color green where we entered the correct data.

My .js file:

```
function checkForm()
{
  var error=false;
  var contactName = document.getElementById("contactName");
  var contactLastName = document.getElementById("contactLastName");
  var contactEmail = document.getElementById("contactEmail");
  var contactInfo = document.getElementById("contactInfo");

  if (contactName.value == "")
  {
    document.getElementById('errorName').className='alert alertdanger';
    error=true;
  }

  if (contactLastName.value == "")
  {
    document.getElementById('errorLastName').className='alert alertdanger';
    error=true;
  }

  if(contactInfo.value == "")
  {
    document.getElementById('errorInfo').className='alert alertdanger';
    error = true;
  }
  else
  {
    var info = contactInfo.value;

    if(info.length >= 250)
    {
      document.getElementById('errorInfoLength').className='alert alertdanger';
      error=true;
    }
  }

  if(contactEmail.value == "")
  {
    document.getElementById('errorMail').className='alert alertdanger';
    error=true;
  }
  else
  {
    var email = contactEmail.value;
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,4}$/;

    if(regex.test(email)==false)
    {
      document.getElementById('errorMailCorrect').innerHTML='Bad format!';
      document.getElementById('errorMailCorrect').className='alert alertdanger';
      error=true;
    }
  }

  if (!error)
    return true;
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="index.html#kontakt" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
      <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group" id="error1">
        <p id="errorName" class="d-none">Add name!</p>
        <label for="contactName">Imię</label>
        <input type="text" id="contactName"/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" id="error2">
        <p id="errorLastName" class="d-none">Add last name!</p>
        <label for="contactLastName">Nazwisko</label>
        <input type="text" id="contactLastName"/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" id="error3">
        <p id="errorMail" class="d-none">Add email!</p>
        <p id="errorMailCorrect" class="d-none">Wrong email!</p>
        <label for="contactEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="contactEmail" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" id="error4">
        <p id="errorInfo" class="d-none">Add info!</p>
        <p id="errorInfoLength" class="d-none">Limit is 250 chars!</p>
        <label for="contactInfo">Informacja</label>
        <input type="text" id="contactInfo" />
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

In bootrap 3.4.1 I could simply add to my .js file:

```
document.getElementById("error1").className="form-group has-error";
```

What is the equivalent of "form-group has-error" in Boostrap 4?

Also another question. What do you need to do to make the fields on the form validate the details you have entered immediately? Not after we submitted them.

Comment: _"When we send information with errors"_ Ideally a form should display possible validation-errors before you send it -  the validation should happen constantly on events such as key-up/key-down and not after submission (as you already aware of according to your last sentence)..

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/?#how-it-works). You can:

- Use the `:valid` and `:invalid` CSS pseudo-classes. They only work if the form has the class `.was-validated`.
- Or use the `.is-valid` and `is-invalid` CSS classes.

Validating before submitting can be done using standard HTML attributes such as `required`, `pattern`, etc.. If that does not cover your requirements, you can do it yourself with JavaScript. But that is a whole other topic and it is probably best to use some library or framework for that.